# SharePoint 2013 Newsfeed video button

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microblogging

[SharePoint 2013 My site microblog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqeDI.png)

Help creating a button like the image upload button in the picture attached above, but for uploading/posting videos in microblog.

The javascript code could include a link to an asset library that videos could be uploaded to after which the url of the video will be fetched and pasted in the microblog also which SharePoint page or resource will need to be modified to ensure all users have this button.

Thank you

Comment: And, what have you tried????

Comment: We are here to help you not to make for you

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming. I've looked at some links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx. But I'm not sure if they apply or how to implement even if they do.